# refresh listview every two minutes android

Tags: android, listview

I am attempting to refresh my `ListView` every two seconds.  First `loadingTask`  is executed, and adapter populates the ListView from arraylist chat. Then for every two seconds, `refreshAdapterLoadingTask` is called and executed as a continuous loop and populate the arraylist chat again. I need to remove the previous items from `ArrayList` and keep new one only. any idea of how such last for the road function can be implemented please. At present, My array keeps populating items from previous httpcall as a loop.

```
int refreshInterval =2000; //set refresh interval

class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {

//arraylist
    chat = new ArrayList<Chat>();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ...

                for (int i=0;i<room_length;i++){
                JSONObject obj_value = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (obj_value.has("@id"))
                    id=obj_value.getString("@id");

                if (obj_value.has("@version"))
                    version=obj_value.getString("@version");

        ...


            chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(m,chat);
            msgList.setAdapter(chatAdapter); //set data to listview
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//update changes
            msgList.setSelection(msgList.getAdapter().getCount()-1);


            handler.postDelayed(refreshView, refreshInterval);


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        return null;
    }




        public static class refreshAdapterLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {

    private String isMarketingMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        //if(chat!=null)
            //chat.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            ...

            for (int i=0;i< responseArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj_value = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (obj_value.has("@id"))
                    id=obj_value.getString("@id");

                if (obj_value.has("@version"))
                    version=obj_value.getString("@version");

                if (obj_value.has("@content"))
                    content=obj_value.getString("@content");

                if (obj_value.has("@sentDate"))
                    sentDate=obj_value.getString("@sentDate");

                if (obj_value.has("player"))
                    player=obj_value.getString("player");

                chat.add(new Chat(isMarketingMessage, id, version,content, sentDate, player));


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        //remove previous arraylist values
    //  for (int i=0;i<previousArrayListSize;i++){
        //  chat.remove(i);
        //}



        handler.postDelayed(refreshView, refreshInterval);

        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(m,chat);
        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }
}



}
```

**Updates**

```
public static void process() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                // LiveScoredata();
                new refreshAdapterLoadingTask().execute();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            m.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    try {

                        if (chat!=null)
                            chat.clear();

                        //your list fill hear 
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }).start();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Using Timer and Runnable method you can list refresh

Timer  t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
                   // your process 
        process();
    }

}, 0, 2000);

// Process method
private void process() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                // LiveScoredata();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        //your list fill hear 
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }).start();

}
```

Comment: Above adapter notifydatasetchanged clear arraylist and fill arraylist

Comment: check updates i put your code with what you told me to do but if i clear chat arraylist all records will be gone before updates

Comment: After clear array list fill data in list or adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); use this.

Comment: then  if (chat!=null) chat.clear(); and fill your adapter and set your adapter in listview.

Comment: while chat arraylist becomes null arrayadapter will be null also

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        //automatically disappear after given time and start game
        public void run() {
            //call your loadingTask here
        }
    }, refreshInterval);
```

And call same method in post execute

Hope this will help you

Comment: i need to delete previously set item from arraylist only without user notify arraylist was clear